# SQLite remove duplicates from table which has multiple rows with same primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

My question is to list all directors who directed 10 movies or more, in descending order of the number of movies they directed. Return the directors' names and the number of movies each of them directed

I have two tables one is Director table which has ID(primary key), MID, PID columns. and other is the Person table which has PID(primary key), Name, Gender columns.

Following is my query

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) movies_directed
FROM Director
LEFT JOIN Person USING(PID)
GROUP BY PID
HAVING movies_directed >= 10
ORDER BY movies_directed DESC;
```

But here the problem is, there are multiple rows with the same PID in Person.

Here is the sample data

When I execute query

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE '%Andy Serkis%';
```

result is

```
index        PID          Name           Gender
4        'nm0785227'     **' Andy Serkis'**  'Male'
36821    'nm0785227'     'Andy Serkis'   'Male'
```

There is an extra space for Name in the first row. These duplicates need to be removed

Comment: *there are multiple rows with the same PID in Person* is this true???? Isn't PID the primary key in table Person?

Comment: Yes there are multiple rows with the same PID and PID is the primary key in Person table

Comment: @rajashekar read this: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/ so you understand what a **primary key** is. If you can't provide the necessary info for your question don't expect any help.

Comment: @forpas I know there should be only one unique primary key. But this is the dataset I have where I need to delete those duplicate rows in the Person table

Comment: @rajashekar PID is **not** a primary key if there are duplicate PIDs inside the table Person. If you want to delete the duplicates then say so in your question.

Comment: @rajashekar what is the column index in your results?

Comment: That is not a column. It is just the index of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But here the problem is there are multiple rows with the same PID in Person.

This doesn't really make sense.  Presumably, `PID` is the primary key for the `Person` table.  That would mean that there is only one row per value in `Person`.  There may be multiple rows in `Director` --  because a person could direct more than one movie.

I think your query would return the right results.  However, it is not phrased correctly.

It would be better to use an inner join, because you are only considering people who have directed at least one movie (well, at least 10 in fact).  So:

```
SELECT p.Name, COUNT(*) as movies_directed
FROM Person p JOIN
     Director d
     USING (PID)
GROUP BY PID, p.Name
HAVING movies_directed >= 10
ORDER BY movies_directed DESC;
```

Notes:

- When you refer to multiple tables you should qualify all column names.  The one exception are columns in the `USING` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- In your version, you have `COUNT(*)`.  That is not usually appropriate with a `LEFT JOIN`.  Usually, you would want to count matches in the *second* table.

Comment: There are multiple rows with the same PID in Person table. So we need to remove duplicates first and then we should join two tables

Comment: Adding DISTINCT trim(Name) in the first line got my answer but my doubt is why you have grouped by both PID and Name instead of only PID

Comment: @rajashekar . . . In general, you should aggregate by all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) movies_directed
FROM Director
Where exists
(SELECT 1 FROM  Person 
WHERE Director.PID = Person.PID)
GROUP BY PID
HAVING movies_directed >= 10
ORDER BY movies_directed DESC;
```

But ideally, you'd want to refer to a separate table with unique person id and use a join clause.

Comment: There is no Name field in the Director table. It is going to throw an error

Comment: In that case, use CTE, with unique PID. the duplicate records appear to be due to white spaces in front. Use appropriate text functions or so to make them unique.

Answer (score 0):

First execute this `DELETE` statement:

```
delete from Person 
where exists (
  select 1 from Person p 
  where p.pid = Person.pid and p.name <> Person.name and p.rowid < Person.rowid
);
```

this deletes duplicate `PID`s and keeps only the one with the lower [`RowId`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html).
Then execute this `UPDATE` statement:

```
update Person
set name = trim(name);
```

to fix any names that contain spaces at the end or the beginning.
If there are other inconsistencies too you can execute similar `UPDATE` statements.
Then your code should work if you use the proper aliases for the tables and qualify the columns with them.

Comment: It is throwing an error "Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time." while executing the first query (that is deleting the duplicates)

Comment: How do you execute the statement?Execute only that.